# Как изменить отображение в графике Excel

Tags: excel

Стоит задача разместить, места занятые командой в чемпионатах. Нужно что бы первое место было самым высоким, а например 8 самым низким.

Как надо:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что у меня:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Создал таблицу, где указаны места и год. Добавил третью строку, где каждому занятому месту присвоил второе значение: 1==8, 2=7, 3=6 и так далее. Создал гистограмму, скрыл значения второй строки. А затем вручную подправил подписи данных.

Answer (score 1):

Удобство способа, описанного ниже - при изменении данных не нужно вручную исправлять подписи  и данные для графика.

Вставить строку между годами и данными. Там вписать формулу:

```
=РАНГ(B3;$B$3:$K$3)
```

Тип диаграммы - гистограма с накоплением. Данные - диапазон `$B$2:$K$3`. Подписи оси категорий - из диапазона `$B$1:$K$1`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для верхнего ряда:

- добавить подписи данных, формат подписей - *У основания внутри*
- *Формат ряда данных - Заливка - нет заливки*.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]